# Azure Function App create cannot select existing storage account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-account

I have always to create a new storage account (same resource group) when I create a function app.

The system either proposes a name or I can enter my own and but no way can I enter an already existing storage account. Of course, if I want to create a new one with the same name it does not allow it as it already exists.

Why's that? What setting determines this?

The existing storage account is "StorageV2 (general purpose v2)" and the newly created one for the func app is "Storage (general purpose v1)"

So I'd thought perhaps this is the reason but I created a new func app and again it did not let me again choose an existing storage account (for example the storage account created for the first func app) so I would have had to create a new one.

Is this by design?

Comment: Hello @zen, Is the FunctionApp location same as the existing storage account ? if they are same then you can use existing storage account by selecting from the drop down..

Comment: follow this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/76485/change-storage-account-of-azure-function.html) to change the storage account used by your function app. You have to stop the func app, and then make this change. Yes, by design, during creation of the Function app via Azure Portal, you cannot change. After the func app got created, you can change using above method.

Comment: @UserP, by location you mean the region?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran yes, this seems to be, thanks. "Yes, by design, during creation of the Function app via Azure Portal, you cannot change." so this is a feature not a bug :)

Comment: @zen the portal behavior is currently as such, I am not sure if it is by design :). I have added it as answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at present, by design, during creation of the Function app via Azure Portal, you *cannot* change the storage account, though the portal UI seems to indicate you can link to one of the existing and compatible storage accounts. After the function app gets created, you can change it using the method described in this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/76485/change-storage-account-of-azure-function.html).

Answer (score 4):

For me, the `function app` location was not same as the `storage account` location.

Setting the same location for both started showing up existing storage accounts in the drop down.